# cannot block site through /etc/hosts

Tags: hosts, etc

I'm trying to block site with configuring `/etc/hosts` file.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "0.0.0.0 http://youtube.com" >> /etc/hosts'
```

but I still can access youtube from browser(s). even I changed the domain to `127.0.0.1` but it didn't work.

Comment: /etc/hosts is only there to list static host names to IP. It wouldn't block anything. To block sites you need a firewall. Check https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Gufw , or, better, learn to use `iptables`. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

/etc/hosts only deals with the *hostname* you are accessing, not the whole web address.  So to block `http://youtube.com/...`, you only want to specify `youtube.com` because that is the host.

Note that YouTube actually uses `www.youtube.com` (with the www) and that is considered a different hostname so you'd have to block that too.

The final thing to note is that this just blocks your ability for your DNS system to be able to look up YouTube by its hostname.  It is not securely blocking YouTube, as users may be able to look up its IP addresses some other way.  A determined user could do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo sh -c 'echo "0.0.0.0 youtube.com" >> /etc/hosts'`

Answer (score 0):

just type www.youtube.com in the /etc/hosts file